# uncaught syntaxerror unexpected string

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, syntax-error

I'm trying to make a drop-down menu, works fine in firefox
It does not work in other browsers

get the following error:

```
jQuery(".parent").hover(  function () {
    jQuery(this).toggleClass("activeli").(".parent").stop(true, true).slideToggle(); << error line
});
```

This is the web link
http://www.jeanca.com/clientes/evoca/

Comment: Firefox says "Error: XML filter is applied to non-XML value ({0:#1=({}), context:#1#, length:1})
Source File: http://www.jeanca.com/clientes/evoca/
Line: 55". It must just keep going where other browsers bail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is `toggleClass("activeli").(".parent")` Probably should be.

```
jQuery(this).toggleClass("activeli").find(".parent").stop(true, true).slideToggle();
```